# Missing FROM-clause entry for table x

Tags: postgresql

I've got a mistake where I can't put data from this query into the csv file.
Error is

> Missing FROM-clause entry for table x

```sql
psql -t -A -F ';' -h localhost -U username -c "with x as 
(select created::timestamp(0), phone_number, from_addr, to_addr, price, 
completion_status_name from archived_order where ds_id = 510) 
select x.created, x.phone_number, x.from_addr, x.to_addr, x.price, 
x.completion_status_name order by x.created;" > someName.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
psql -t -A -F ';' -h localhost -U username -c "with x as 
(select created::timestamp(0), phone_number, from_addr, to_addr, price, 
completion_status_name from archived_order where ds_id = 510) 
select x.created, x.phone_number, x.from_addr, x.to_addr, x.price, 
x.completion_status_name **from x** order by x.created;" > someName.csv
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are never sufficient answers. Please add an explanation, and please highlight how your answer's code differs from op's.